# How to store/access a session variable in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session, state, asp.net-core-webapi

I understand that a Restful API should not have session variables, but I simply want to store whether the user has `AdminMode` enabled or not.

I do not want to store this variable in a database.

How can I store this variable in ASP.NET Core Web API?

Comment: The proper way to do this is to use a claim in the bearer token.

Comment: If you are using `JWT` based authentication for your `Web API` you can simply retrieve from your token claims which is easy and convenient that ensure `APIs` safety. You can check the [`example here in official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-6.0#save-the-access-token)

Answer (score 2):

If you application doesn't have any requirements for availablity or doesn't have to be scalable, meanig all requests goes directly to a single server, then you can get away with in-memory session variables. Just dont use it as a persistent store. E.g.

[image]

Otherwise, if you have your application deployed across several machines, any state on one machine usually have to be present on other machines as well so you have to synchronize it. Which is usually done with some kind of database or a queue.

[image]

In asp.net you have a mechanism to store to store session data

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("YouData", "SomeData");
```

You have  to set it up first, you can find detailed instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0). By default it's going to use in-memory data store which is not a distributed cache, not a thread safe cache and not recommended for production. There are a few "out of the box" implementations for redis, sql server and NCache,  you can find more information about them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-5.0#distributed-memory-cache)

In case you use [JWT token](https://jwt.io/introduction), you can store this information in a token payload